# Extending visa-free stay in Sweden to a Visitor's Permit, how does that apply to 90/180 rule?

Tags: schengen, long-stay-visas, visa-extensions, 90-180-visa-rules, visa-expiration

My partner origins from Taiwan and would like to visit me in Sweden, for as long as possible. The idea is to apply for a Sambo Visa before she comes to Sweden and hopefully get it approved before she needs to go back.

Our plan so far is for her to visit Sweden on visa exemption (3 months) and 2 months in apply to extend it to a Visitor's Permit (3 months hopefully). Which will give her a residence permit card because she'll be staying longer than 3 months. My question starts after these 6 months, how does the 90/180 rule apply here?

Now looking at this link:
https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/border-crossing/docs/short_stay_schengen_calculator_user_manual_en.pdf

It states

> Periods of stay authorised under a residence permit or a long-stay visa shall not be
>   taken into account in the calculation of the duration of stay on the territory of the Member
>   States.

Does the above mean that if we are allowed to extend her stay by another 3 months (she will stay 6 months in total) that once the Visitor's Permit ends she can again use her visa-free period but is required to go out of Sweden for 1 day and then come back in to re-activate it?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Stay golden

Comment: Is your partner allowed to enter Sweden at all while a Sambo application is in progress?

Comment: Yes, though I know this wasn't the case 2-3 years ago. Not sure when they changed that but I have been in contact with the Swedish Migration Agency about it and they confirmed it